# Calling Microsoft QnA maker API from Node.js using request module

Tags: node.js, request, azure-cognitive-services

Below is my code for calling the microsoft QnA maker API using request module in Node.js.

```js
var request=require('request');


var demo=[];
console.log("Doing the Post Operations...");
// Define an demo object with properties and values. This object will be used for POST request.

var demo=JSON.stringify({
    "question": "Hi",
    "top": 1
});


request({
    uri:"https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/my_kb_id/generateAnswer",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,   
 headers:{
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'my_key',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
  body: demo
 
 
}, function (error, response, body){
    console.log(response);
});
```

This is returning me the 'Bad Argument' error. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Do you mean the response from the server is an error? What's the exact, full response?

Comment: Oh, I don't think you should be `JSON.stringify`ing your request body. The `request` library is going to do that again because you set the option `json: true`, so you're probably sending double-encoded JSON.

Comment: Per the documentation, it seems like the error should include a `message` that tells you the specific issue. (I think I guessed the issue anyway from looking at your code, but if not, we really need to know what the error is.)

Comment: Yes, you guessed the issue right. After I changed the code it is now returning the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on code for calling Microsoft QnA maker API using request module in Node.js.The below code is working fine. Instead of using JSON.stringify I am directly passing the demo as JSON.

```
var request=require('request');

var demo={"question" : "hi",
           "top": 4};

url='https://accountqna.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/my_kb_id/generateAnswer';
atuhorisationKey="EndpointKey <atuhorisationKey>"

 request({
                                    url: url,
                                    method: "POST",
                                    headers:{
                                            'Authorization':atuhorisationKey,
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                            },
                                    json:demo
                                }, function (error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                                console.log(body)
                            }
                            else {

                                console.log("error: " + error)
                                console.log("response.statusCode: " + response.statusCode)
                                console.log("response.statusText: " + response.json)
                            }
                        })
```